# MyBatis, change Database type dinamically based on the environment

Tags: java, oracle, postgresql, mybatis

I have a REST based java web application with Java 8, MyBatis 3.4.5, deployed on Wildfly application server.
In this application I have a DB jar module which manages all the queries, connections, Objects ... from/to the application/DB. All my other Java code (controllers, method, classes) which has to interact with the DB use this DB module.

As a standard MyBatis implementation I have those packages inside the DB module

- my/app/oj/db/**client** *contains all java file responsible of translating all the queries to/from java objects* (**UserMapper.java**)
- my/app/oj/db/**mapper** *contains all the queries inside xml* (**UserMapper.xml**)
- my/app/oj/db/**model** *model package* (**User.java**)
- my/app/oj/db/**manager** *query service definitions* (**UserManager.java**)

the content of those classes and xml files changes based on the underlying DB type (PostgreSQL, Oracle) because of different DB syntax, DB datatypes and so on.

When I need to query the DB I have something like this:

```
my.app.oj.db.manager.UserManager userManager = new  my.app.oj.db.manager.UserManager();
List<my.app.oj.db.model.User> users = userManager.selectAllUsers();
```

so basically my Manager package defines how the query is made

In one environment I use PostgreSQL as database. 
My myBatis config file is:

```
<configuration>
<environments default="development">
    <environment id="development">
        <transactionManager type="JDBC" />
        <dataSource type="POOLED">
            <property name="poolMaximumActiveConnections" value="15" />
            <property name="driver" value="${posgresValue}" />
            <property name="url" value="${url} />
            <property name="username" value="${username}" />
            <property name="password" value="${password}" />
        </dataSource>
    </environment>
</environments>
<mappers>
    <package name="my/app/oj/db/mapper/" />
</mappers>
</configuration>
```

Now I have to add another environment, which use Oracle as db, so it will have different connections url, username and password, AND, MOST OF ALL, **it will have differents mappers, both java and xml files**. I don't need to connect to those DB simultaneously, but I have to choose one of them depending on the environment I deploy my application.

Using differents db-data-config.xml file I will set the connection properties and the Mappers.xml based on the environment, but how do I change which java classes are called ?

I know I can duplicate the all the DB module of my project and change it during the build/deploy phase, but I need to keep it single, and differentiate the packages.

I want to obtain something like this

- my/app/oj/db/**oracle**/client
- my/app/oj/db/**oracle**/mapper
- my/app/oj/db/**oracle**/model
- my/app/oj/db/**oracle**/manager
- my/app/oj/db/**postgres**/client
- my/app/oj/db/**postgres**/mapper
- my/app/oj/db/**postgres**/model
- my/app/oj/db/**postgres**/manager

and add some other database support in the future, like MySql and so on...
So when I will query the DB, the java manager will change based on my needs.

```
my.app.oj.db.<PostgreSQL>.manager.UserManager userManager = new  my.app.oj.db.<PostgreSQL>.manager.UserManager();
List<my.app.oj.db.<PostgreSQL>.model.User> users = userManager.selectAllUsers();
```

How can I obtain this? I can't find a way to have MyBatis handle this, and perhaps this in not a "ORM" problem, but rather a java pattern instead.

Thanks to all.

Comment: MyBatis' [multi-db vendor support](https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/dynamic-sql.html#Multi-db_vendor_support) takes a different approach. Basically, you have one mapper for all DBs and when you need a different SQL for one of them, you add a new statement with the same ID but with a different `_databaseId` specified. You may also need to add `databaseIdProvider` in the [config](https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/configuration.html#databaseIdProvider) to detect DB at runtime. This approach may be more efficient because not everything needs to be different, usually.

Comment: I know about multi-db vendor support, but it can't handle differents manager and mapper.java files. For example, how do you manage selectByExample and selectByExampleWithBlob queries? (the first for postgres and the secon for oracle DB, with a table with json column)

Comment: If you are trying to use MyBatis Generator, that might not fit the multi-db vendor support very well. The idea is to use the same statement for all DBs and change the actual SQL executed by the statement. But the feature assumes that the objects returned from a query is the same for all DBs and this might not be the case with your design, maybe? (you seem to have different models for each DB) I then wonder how you write service/presentation layer using those DB-dependent model objects. 

Comment: I use MyBatis Generator, I managed to mantain the same model, even if I have different DB. I am not able to  write service/presentation layer using those DB-dependent model objects and that is one of the problem I asked.

Comment: I see. If there are not many DB dependent SQLs, you should exclude them from the target of MyBatis Generator and write the statements manually. It still seems better than maintaining different logic for each DB. It might also be possible to write a custom [plugin](http://mybatis.org/generator/reference/pluggingIn.html) that generates vendor specific statements based on the metadata (e.g. generate a separate statement if a table contains JSON columns), but I really am not sure if it's possible (or if it's a good idea).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right that this is not a problem of ORM.

The client of `UserManager` should be isolated from the specific type of the DB and dynamically get the correct `UserManager` implementation like this:

```
DBType dbType = DBType.POSTGRESQL; // DBType is the enum
my.app.oj.db.common.manager.UserManager userManager = my.app.oj.db.common.manager.UserManagerFactory.getManager(dbType);
List<my.app.oj.db.common.model.User> users = userManager.selectAllUsers();
```

Note that client code does not know about specific types of `UserManager` or `User`. It works by using `common` types which are interfaces that are implemented for specific DBs.

You either need to have one `User` model that is shared by all implementations or you will need an interface like the following that all models will implement:

`my/app/oj/db/common/model/User.java`:

```
interface User {
  String getName();
  ...
}
```

Then interface for user manager:

`my/app/oj/db/common/manager/UserManager.java`:

```
interface UserManager {
  List<my.app.oj.db.common.model.User> selectAllUsers();
}
```

Now implementations for specific user manager for postgres for example:

`my/app/oj/db/postgres/manager/UserManager.java`:

```
class UserManager implements my.app.oj.db.common.manager.UserManager {
   public List<my.app.oj.db.common.model.User> selectAllUsers() {
     // uses postgres specific mappers to return
     // list containing instances of my.app.oj.db.common.postgres.model.User if
     // you used db specific model implementation
   }
}
```

And finally `UserManagerFactory`:

```
class UserManagerFactory {
   my.app.oj.db.common.manager.UserManager getManager(DBType dbType) {
    switch (dbType) {
      case DBType.POSTGRES:
        return new my.app.oj.db.postgres.manager.UserManager();
      case DBType.ORACLE:
        return new my.app.oj.db.oracle.manager.UserManager(); 
   } 
}
```